# .htaccess - Disable basic auth for specific path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I run a testsystem with a htaccess basic auth:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I now want to disable this auth for all user who target the /api and /api/orders etc. of this server. I tried it with this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api(.*)$" api_uri
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=api_uri
Satisfy any
```

But this does not work - mod_setenvif is enabled. Does anybody have an idea why this is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a Location/Directory entry for /api in which you just "Allow from all" and "Satisfy any"?

Answer (score 3):

Have it this way:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /api api_uri

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=api_uri
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work for other urls behind /api? Like api/orders etc?

Comment: Since we are only matching `/api ` it will match anything as well that comes after `/api`

Comment: When I visit /api and cancel the Auth, I can see the json responce that I am unauthorized. When I try to open /api/orders/ I get a server error that I am not authorized (from the htaccess). So it does not work. I also tried it with SetEnvIf Request_URI "\/api(.*)$" api_uri, but this is also not working.

Comment: Try restarting your browser. I've tested these exact directives in my .htaccess and there is no auth dialogue for anything starting with `/api`

Comment: I suggest you clear the browser cache. Browsers tend to cache this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I normally just add a separate `.htaccess` file inside the `api` folder:

```
Satisfy any
```

Comment: I do not have a folder named /api/ ... its a rewrite from the cms that I use.

Comment: Oh, they you cannot do this. You can probably replace it with `<Location /api>` but I haven't tried it.